Mac accessibility and non-native widgets
I am developing accessibility support for the Tcl/Tk toolkit, and am currently working on macOS with the C-based Accessibility API. I'm trying to understand how to create accessibility objects for the various Tk widgets, which are NOT wrappers of Mac-based widgets (they are drawn using Mac API's, but there are no wrappers of NSButton, for instance).
The Accessibility API shows how to create a top-level accessibility object:
pid_t pidt = getpid();
AXUIElementRef acc_app = AXUIElementCreateApplication(pidt);

What is not clear, however, is how to create AXUIElementRef objects from the child widgets that would populate in the application. This code iterates through the child AXUIElementRefs in the application:
CFArrayRef attArray;
AXUIElementCopyAttributeNames(acc_app, &attArray);
NSLog(@"%@", attArray ? (__bridge NSArray *)attArray : @"nil");

CFTypeRef childrenPtr;
AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(app, kAXChildrenAttribute, &childrenPtr);
NSArray *children = (__bridge NSArray *)childrenPtr;
NSLog(@"%@", children);

if (attArray) CFRelease(attArray);
if (childrenPtr) CFRelease(childrenPtr);

But I'm not clear how to designate the widgets with the kAXChildrenAttribute.
I found this function call:
AXUIElementSetAttributeValue(AXUIElementRef element, CFStringRef attribute, CFTypeRef value) 

This appears to allow me to designate a child widget with the "children" attribute--would I have to somehow convert a Tk_Window (the child window in C) to a CFTypeRef to build that association? Has anyone else done with with non-native widgets?

There are two Accessibility APIs. One to make your app accessible (Accessibility for AppKit) and another to access other apps (AXUIElement…).

Thank you, this is helpful.

Looks like NSAccessibilityElement is what I'm looking for. The docs at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsaccessibilityelement-swift.class?language=objc are helpful.
